# position:fixed divs move when opening a 'select' element on iphone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, css

I've got various fixed divs in my page, like a header, navigation bar etc.

They work fine on mobile, until I click to open a select form element on an iPhone.

Its as if the header is no longer fixed and actually becomes more like position:absolute, where it scrolls with the content.

This is particularly annoying as when you open a select on iPhone, it scrolls the page slightly to make sure the select stays in view as the options slide up, which mean my fixed header moves around.

Anyone got ideas how to fix this? can use jQuery/ javascript to solve

Comment: Add code or don't expect many answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this with the below jquery, it just stops the content scrolling when selecting a form element. You have to have the 1ms delay for it to work for some reason. Maybe this will help someone else:

```
$('input, select, textarea').on('focus',function() {
    var curScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:curScroll},1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the web browsers do not support the CSS property `position:fixed;`. I recommend you use the http://jquerymobile.com/ for a complete mobile UI Solution.

*NB:  iOS 5 and Android 4 are both reported to have position:fixed support now.